# Add a poster to an embeb Vimeo video

Tags: html, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'd like to know if someone know's a way to add a custom poster image to an embebed VIMEO video.
I couldn't find anything in their Documentation, but i'm hopping I missed something.

The current code looks like this

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/50315573" ></iframe>
</div>
```